# In android studio using libgdx showing error about could not download gdx.jar

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Error:

> A problem occurred configuring project ':android'.
>   Could not download gdx.jar (com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:1.9.6)
>   Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/badlogicgames/gdx/gdx/1.9.6/gdx-1.9.6.jar'.
>   Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/badlogicgames/gdx/gdx/1.9.6/gdx-1.9.6.jar'.
>   repo1.maven.org

Comment: show `build.gradle` file

Comment: Did you click IDEA build under advanced in the LibGDX project setup program and then import as Gradle project? I might have had the same issues a couple months ago when upgrading the LibGDX setup and AS.